# Detect windows 2003 and XP using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Need to write a batch file which should run different commands depending on windows version. Trying to use the following batch, it doesn't work

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims=." %%a IN ('ver') DO (

SET WVer=%%a
SET WVer=!WVer:~-1!
SET WVer=!WVer!.%%b.%%c
SET WVer=!WVer:]=!
)

ECHO %WVer%

set result=false
if %WVer%==5.1.2600 set result=true
if %WVer%==5.2.3790 set result=true
if "%result%" == "true" (
    GOTO  XPor2003
)
if "%result%" == "false" (
 GOTO  nope
)


:XPor2003
echo XPor2003

:nope
echo nope
```

copy of my comments: Here is a result of my batch script on a Windows XP:

```
5.2.3790 x64 
XPor2003
nope
```

I'm just wondering why `nope` result is shown. I'm trying to figure out why my batch script transfers control to incorrect label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the three `goto :EOF` commands which help with the program flow.

```
set result=false
if %WVer%==5.1.2600 set result=true
if %WVer%==5.2.3790 set result=true
if "%result%" == "true" (
    GOTO  XPor2003
)
if "%result%" == "false" (
 GOTO  nope
)
goto :EOF


:XPor2003
echo XPor2003
goto :EOF

:nope
echo nope
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Identify OS
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do set ver=%%a
set Version=
for %%a in (95=95 98=98 ME=ME NT=NT 2000=2000 5.1.=XP 5.2.=2003 6.0.=Vista 6.1.=7 6.2.=8) do (
    if "!Version!" equ "this" (
        set Version=Windows %%a
    ) else if "!ver: %%a=!" neq "%ver%" (
        set Version=this
    )
)

::Identify bit
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)" (
    set Type=64 bit
) else (
    set Type=32 bit
)

::Display result
echo %Version% %Type%
goto :eof


::Goto right version
goto %Version: =_%


:Windows_8
echo Windows 8

:Windows_7
echo Windows 7
```

<sub>*© Aacini*</sub>

Comment: Here is a result of my batch script on a Windows XP:

`5.2.3790 x64
XPor2003
nope`

I'm just wondering why `nope` result is shown.

Comment: I get `Windows XP 32 bit` here on my XP system and `Windows 8 64 bit` on my win8 system.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why my batch script transfers control to incorrect label